# XSD restrict tag content depending upon attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like define an XSD that allows an element to have specific children regarding one of its attribute value. This attribute values are defined using multiple `xsd:enumeration`.

Here is how my XML can be :

```
<root>
    <Conversion type="Phys" />
    <Conversion type="Fact">
        <Factor>13</Factor>
        <Offset>37</Offset>
    </Conversion>
    <Conversion type="List">
        <Item>
            <Key>0</Key>
            <Value>KEY_0</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Value>KEY_1</Value>
        </Item>
    </Conversion>
</root>
```

So far, I have managed to restrict the `Conversion` tag to have only these 3 attributes and only these 3 sequences as children (`Factor`/`Offset` ; `Item` list ; nothing).

Here is a bit of my XSD :

```
<xs:element name="Conversion">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Key" type="xs:decimal" />
                            <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Factor" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element name="Offset" type="xs:double" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence />
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="Type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Fact" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="List" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="Phys" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What I would like to do is to restrict the children according to the value of my attribute to avoid forbid mixing attributes and contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need XSD 1.1 to do exactly what you request, make a content model dependent upon the value of an attribute.   You can use Conditional Type Assignment or even assertions.

However, if you can adjust your XML design, you can use basic XSD 1.0 (and XSD 1.1 as well):

```
<root>
    <Phys/>
    <Fact>
        <Factor>13</Factor>
        <Offset>37</Offset>
    </Fact>
    <List>
        <Item>
            <Key>0</Key>
            <Value>KEY_0</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Value>KEY_1</Value>
        </Item>
    </List>
</root>
```

**Type information is generally better conveyed via a more specific element name than via augmentation of a generic element name with a type attribute.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! I see what you mean. Actually, the `Conversion` tag is part of a `Variable` type with other siblings. So it describes the "type of conversion" of its variable. I gonna try with XSD 1.1